# Complexity of using pagination/sorting through DB or using stream Java API?

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, pagination, java-stream

I have two solutions for pagination and sorting data.

> 1) I can create a Mongo DB query which will create pagination and sorting for me.
>
> 2) I can get all data and use streaming to do sorting first and than apply pagination on it.

**Main issue**

I have to do some custom sorting on strings and do a ignore case AlphaNumeric sort which is not provided by mongo DB. I have a solution right now only for ignore case which is ugly. (I can find something for AN sort as well)

I can achieve this sort easily if I get all records from Db and write any compartor and sort the record and than apply pagination using stream api.

**Performance Guidance required**

Which option is like more suitable and is less complex? Or which option will remain best?

Comment: if u have a lot of data may be its faster to do on DB side; if there are not *I* would do it in java code; but that's just me

Comment: I kindly disagree with @Eugene on this one: always let the DB do the sorting and pagination stuff; but it's just me :)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner the thing is OP said this being kind of clunky on Mongo ( which I have close to zero experience with and I do trust him on that), thus my segestion... Otherwise Ill agree with u

Comment: @Eugene I don't have experience with Mongo either, have always used Couchbase and Elasticsearch :) But I find it really hard to believe that sorting needs to be done on the server side because a database (any database) is not good at sorting. I think the real problem is indeed how to sort in Mongo. The famous XY problem...

Comment: You almost always want to do the pagination on database to avoid transferring 1000 of rows from DB to application just to ignore 90% of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Stream<String[]> fetchDispLst(String[][] items, int sortParam ,int sortOrder ,int itemsPerPage ,int pageNo   ) {

     List<String[]> strmlist = Stream.of(items).sorted((first,second)->  {  
         if (sortOrder == 0) { 
             final String time1 = first[sortParam];
             final String time2 = second[sortParam];
             int compare = time1.compareTo(time2);
             if(compare != 0){
                 return compare;
             }
             return compare;
          }else {
              final String time1 = first[sortParam];
                 final String time2 = second[sortParam];
                 int compare = time2.compareTo(time1);
                 if(compare != 0){
                     return compare;
                 }
                 return compare;
          }
             }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return strmlist.subList((pageNo - 1) * itemsPerPage ,  strmlist.size()).stream();

   }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.